# Issues with KeyListener and Timer in Java Pong game

Tags: java

I am currently trying to build a basic Pong game in Java, and I am having difficulty with two things. The first is that my rackets move up and down as they should, but once they reach the edge of the frame, they completely freeze up. I cannot figure why. Next, I am not sure how to use Timer or Thread.sleep to momentarily pause the game after each score. Once one of the players score, I want the game to return the ball back to the center and have it wait for about 3 seconds before the ball moves again to start the next point. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Here is my code

Pong Class

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Pong extends JFrame{

    public static final int appWIDTH = 500;     //width of jframe
    public static final int appHEIGHT = 500;    //height of jframe
    public final int rWIDTH = 20;               //width of racket
    public final int rHEIGHT = 60;              //height of racket
    PongPanel panel;                            //Jpanel to be added


    /*
     * constructor for a Pong object
     */
    public Pong() {
        setSize(appWIDTH, appHEIGHT);
        setTitle("PONG");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    /*
     * Starts the application
     */
    public void start() {
        panel = new PongPanel(this);
        add(panel);
        addKeyListener(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    //Returns a PongPanel
    public PongPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pong game = new Pong();
        game.start();
    }
}
```

Panel class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class PongPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    private Pong game;
    private Ball ball;
    private Racket p1, p2;
    private int score1, score2;
    Timer timer;

    /*
     * Constructor for a PongPanel which is a JPanel that holds two rackets and a ball
     */
    public PongPanel(Pong game) {
        this.game = game;   
        p1 = new Racket(game, KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_S, 0);
        p2 = new Racket(game, KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, game.getWidth() - game.rWIDTH);
        ball = new Ball(game);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /*
     * Returns the Racket object associated with player 1
     */
    public Racket getRacket1() {
        return p1;
    }

    /*
     * Returns the Racket object associated with player 2
     */
    public Racket getRacket2() {
        return p2;
    }

    //Increases score of the player indicated by the parameter
    public void increaseScore(int playerNo) {
        if(playerNo == 1)
            score1++;
        else
            score2++;
    }

    //Returns the score of the player indicated by the parameter
    public int getScore(int playerNo) {
        if(playerNo == 1)
            return score1;
        else
            return score2;
    }

    public void update() {
        ball.hitBTS();
        p1.move();
        p2.move();
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        p1.kpressed(ke.getKeyCode());
        p2.kpressed(ke.getKeyCode());
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){
        p1.krelease(ke.getKeyCode());
        p2.krelease(ke.getKeyCode());
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {}

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ball.paint(g);
        p1.paint(g);
        p2.paint(g);
        update();
    }
}
```

Ball Class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Ball {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
    private Pong game;
    final int bWIDTH = 30;                  //ball width    
    final int bHEIGHT = 30;                 //ball height
    private int xspeed = 1;                 //horizontal speed of the ball
    private int yspeed = 1;                 //vertical speed of the ball
    int x;                                  //x-coordinate of the ball
    int y;                                  //y-coordinate of the ball


    /*
     * Constructor of a ball object. Sets the ball in the center of frame
     */
    public Ball(Pong game) {
        x = game.getWidth() / 2 - (bWIDTH/2);
        y = game.getHeight() / 2 - (bHEIGHT/2);
        this.game = game;
    }

    /*
     * Checks whether the ball has hit the bottom or top of the frame
     * or if it has reached the left or right edge (score)
     */
    public void hitBTS() {
        x += xspeed;
        y += yspeed;

        if((x + bWIDTH) > game.getWidth()) {
            game.getPanel().increaseScore(1);
            x = game.getWidth() / 2 - (bWIDTH/2);
            y = game.getHeight() / 2 -(bHEIGHT/2);
        }

        else if(x < 0) {
            game.getPanel().increaseScore(2);
            x = game.getWidth() / 2 - (bWIDTH/2);
            y = game.getHeight() / 2 -(bHEIGHT/2);
        }

        else if(y < 0 || (y > game.getHeight() + bHEIGHT)) {
            yspeed = -yspeed;
        }

        checkScore();
        checkCollision();
    }

    //Shows a dialog box indicating the winter if one player reaches 
    //a score of 3
    public void checkScore() {
        if(game.getPanel().getScore(1) == 3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Player 1 wins");
        }
        else if(game.getPanel().getScore(2) == 3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Player 2 wins");
        }
    }

    //Checks if the ball has hit a racket
    public void checkCollision() {
                 if(getBallBounds().intersects(game.getPanel().getRacket1().getBounds()) || 
getBallBounds().intersects(game.getPanel().getRacket2().getBounds())) {
            xspeed = -xspeed;
        }
    }

    public Rectangle getBallBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, bWIDTH, bHEIGHT);
    }   

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, bWIDTH, bHEIGHT);
    }

}
```

Racket Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Racket {

    private Pong game;
    private int yspeed = 0;     //Number of pixels that the racket moves 
    int x;                      //x-coordinate of racket
    int y;                      //y-coordinate of racket
    int keyUp, keyDown;         //key code associated with the key pressed

    /*
     * Constructor for a racket object. Racket receives a keycode and horizontal 
     * starting position. 
     */
    public Racket(Pong game, int keyUp, int keyDown, int x) {
        this.game = game;
        this.x = x;
        this.keyUp = keyUp;
        this.keyDown = keyDown;
        y = game.getHeight()/2;
    }

    /*
     * Indicates how the racket should move depending on its position.
     */
    public void move() {
        if(y > 0 && y < game.getHeight() - game.rHEIGHT)    
            y += yspeed;
        else if(y <= 0) 
            y = y + 3;
        else if(y == game.getHeight() - game.rHEIGHT)
            y = y - 3;
    }

    /*
     * If key has been pressed, the number of pixels the 
     * racket moves becomes positive or negative
     */
    public void kpressed(int keyCode) {
        if(keyCode == keyUp) {
            yspeed = -3;
        }

        if(keyCode == keyDown) 
            yspeed = 3;
    }

    /*
     * When the key is no longer being pressed, the 
     * racket stops moving.
     */
    public void krelease(int keyCode) {
        if(keyCode == keyUp) 
            yspeed = 0;
        else if (keyCode == keyDown)
            yspeed = 0;
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, game.rWIDTH, game.rHEIGHT);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(x, y, game.rWIDTH, game.rHEIGHT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by having a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).  Key events shouldn't directly modify the state of UI or any values the UI might rely, but instead should simply set a flag to indicate which key(s) are currently active.  Use a Swing `Timer` or `Thread` as you main "game loop", through each loop determine if the game is paused, if so do, do nothing, else update the UI state based on the flags and reschedule a repaint

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, change the move method of your racket class as follows:

```
public void move() {
    if(y > 0 && y < game.getHeight() - game.rHEIGHT)    
        y += yspeed;
    else if(y <= 0) 
        y = y + 3;
    else if(y >= game.getHeight() - game.rHEIGHT)
        y = y - 3;
}
```

Otherwise, when y becomes larger than game.getHeight() - game.rHEIGHT, it will freeze as it won't match any of the 3 conditions in the move method again.

To answer your second question, you can change the checkScore method of your Ball class as follows:

```
public void checkScore() {
    if(game.getPanel().getScore(1) == 3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Player 1 wins");
    }
    else if(game.getPanel().getScore(2) == 3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Player 2 wins");
    }
    else {
        x = game.getWidth() / 2 - (bWIDTH/2);
        y = game.getHeight() / 2 - (bHEIGHT/2);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware, calling `Thread.sleep` within the context of the EDT is highly unrecomended, as it will stop the painting process as well

Comment: I tried to do as you said uoyilmaz; however, when the JFrame starts up, I get a black screen for the 3000 milliseconds, and then when the ball and rackets appear, the screen remains frozen.

Comment: As MadProgrammer stated, Thread.sleep will interfere with the painting process, when they're in the same thread. You should change the architecture of your program as he stated in his comment to your question. However, the first part of my answer should still be correct.